# Removing White Spacing Between Images in a Table

Tags: html

I know this has been covered before but the solutions didn't help me - i'm not a programmer but i can handle basic HTML code. I am trying to send a HTML email out that has 11 images placed in a table to become one big image - however white lines appear between rows when i send it.

I have the table style set with `border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"` but this doesn't help - can anyone please give me advice? Also as i am not a programmer I may not understand any complex answers!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled document</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Save for Web Slices (toast offer mailer 2.jpg) --> 
<table style="height: 920px;" id="Table_01" width="650" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><a href="http://www.metroplan.co.uk/2012/#/4/"> <img src="http://mail.bridgemailsystem.com/pms/graphics/metroplan/toast-offer-mailer-2_01.jpg" width="236" height="201" border="0" style="border: 0;"></a></td>
<td colspan="3"><a href="http://www.metroplan.co.uk/2012/#/78/"> <img src="http://mail.bridgemailsystem.com/pms/graphics/metroplan/toast-offer-mailer-2_02.jpg" width="177" height="201" border="0" style="border: 0;"></a></td>
<td colspan="2"><a href="http://www.metroplan.co.uk/2012/#/10/"><img src="http://mail.bridgemailsystem.com/pms/graphics/metroplan/toast-offer-mailer-2_03.jpg" width="237" height="201" border="0" style="border: 0;"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="http://mail.bridgemailsystem.com/pms/graphics/metroplan/toast-offer-mailer-2_04.jpg" width="152" height="155"></td>
<td colspan="3"><a href="http://www.metroplan.co.uk/2012/#/116/"> <img src="http://mail.bridgemailsystem.com/pms/graphics/metroplan/toast-offer-mailer-2_05.jpg" width="173" height="155" border="0" style="border: 0;"></a></td>
<td colspan="2"><a href="http://www.metroplan.co.uk/2012/#/42/"> <img src="http://mail.bridgemailsystem.com/pms/graphics/metroplan/toast-offer-mailer-2_06.jpg" width="180" height="155" border="0" style="border: 0;"></a></td>
<td><img src="http://mail.bridgemailsystem.com/pms/graphics/metroplan/toast-offer-mailer-2_07.jpg" width="145" height="155"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="7"><img src="http://mail.bridgemailsystem.com/pms/graphics/metroplan/toast-offer-mailer-2_08.jpg" width="650" height="237"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="7"><img src="http://mail.bridgemailsystem.com/pms/graphics/metroplan/toast-offer-mailer-2_09.jpg" width="650" height="231"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><a href="http://www.metroplan.co.uk/"> <img src="http://mail.bridgemailsystem.com/pms/graphics/metroplan/toast-offer-mailer-2_10.jpg" width="314" height="95" border="0" style="border: 0;"></a></td>
<td colspan="4"><a href="mailto:marketing@metroplan.co.uk"> <img src="http://mail.bridgemailsystem.com/pms/graphics/metroplan/toast-offer-mailer-2_11.jpg" width="336" height="95" border="0" style="border: 0;"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="152" height="1"></td>
<td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="84" height="1"></td>
<td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="78" height="1"></td>
<td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="11" height="1"></td>
<td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="88" height="1"></td>
<td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="92" height="1"></td>
<td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="145" height="1"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show the actual HTML code you're sending?

Comment: Also, there's [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), among others, for you to *show* us what's going on in order that we can see your code in action.

Comment: You may need to use the style `border:collapse`

Comment: need to post your html and css but you could try `img { border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; }` and the same on `td`'s to see if that removes it.

Comment: Apologies - as freefaller answers it's actually `border-collapse:collapse`...

Comment: how do i add code without it converting into a preview??

Comment: The preview show you how it will be like when you post what's the problem exactly?

Comment: Figured out how to add the code above!

Comment: OK, see my answer most likely setting font size to 0 will solve this issue.

Comment: okay - where in the code should i add that (sorry not very experianced at this!)

Answer (score 24):

On images, try using

```
style="display:block"
```

It should work.

Comment: Surprisingly adding the display:block style to the image fixed the issue for me.

Comment: So helpful! Just saved me a bunch of time. Everybody throw this person your upvotes!

Comment: In addition to this I had to do `margin-top:-1px` for Chrome.

Answer (score 6):

From quick check I just did, looks like the problem is due to blank space inside the cells markup taking up some place and making the cells bigger.

One way around this is setting the font size of the cells to 0 thus eliminating that extra space.

[Live test case with the fix applied](http://jsfiddle.net/SHL3H/).

In your case, try adding this to the HTML you send:

```
<style type="text/css">
    table td { font-size: 0px; }
</style>
```

This is assuming you have only one table and all cells have only images, if you have more tables then give that specific table `id` e.g. `<table id="MyImagesTable">` then change to:

```
#MyImagesTable td { font-size: 0px; }
```

If the email client of those getting the email does not support style sheets you will have to manually set it for each cell:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 0px;">...</td>
        <td style="font-size: 0px;">...</td>
        <td style="font-size: 0px;">...</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ...more rows... -->
</table>
```

Comment: I agree that your answer works, and I can find nothing else that helps (I thought `white-space:nowrap` might help, it didn't)... what I don't get is that in your jsfiddle, there *is* no space between the `<td>`, `<img>` and `</td>` tags... is the browser putting it in there despite the lack of separation?

Comment: @freefaller good point, it leads me to believe the browser is "imposing" font size over images as well. Weird, but weirder stuff happens! :)

Comment: @freefaller just confirmed my assumption. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SHL3H/2/) fiddle with Chrome. Looks like IE is ignoring font size for images though..

Answer (score 3):

I also face same problem.

But i tried

```
<img src ="images/xyz.jpg"  style="display:block">
```

and solved

Answer (score 1):

This problem is common on many mail clients, just use:

```
<img style="display:block" />
```

on every image in your HTML.

Comment: This was already suggested in [other answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11118089/447356) no point repeating it half year later.

Comment: The other answer didn't state where (in the img tag). I think he didn't edit there 'cause he wasn't allowed. Well, I did what he said and it worked in my html for email.

Comment: It worked for me too, and I didn't find the main answer really useful for my case, as I had content.

Answer (score 0):

Without actually having seen your code, I would guess that you're seeing spaces between your images because you have actual space between your images.

If you have something like this...

```
<img src="image1.jpg">
<img src="image2.jpg">
```

Change it to... (note there is no space between the two image tags)

```
<img src="image1.jpg"><img src="image2.jpg">
```

If you are placing the images within individual cells (i.e. one image per cell) then try putting the CSS of `border-collapse:collapse`...

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse">
```

**UPDATE**

As @Shadow has pointed out, neither parts of the above will make any difference.

It appears that FireFox and Chrome deal with the image as it would text (for some reason), therefore his suggestion of `table td { font-size:0px; }` is IMHO the correct answer.  (IE doesn't seem to be effected by the issue.)

Comment: No, [this doesn't solve the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/SHL3H/1/). (See the space between the rows)

Comment: Fair enough, guess I should have tried a jsfiddle myself - thanks @Shadow

Answer (score 0):

A lot of this is flat out ignored by certain mail clients. This is always the risk you take in heavy graphic html emails. You are almost guaranteed to have recipients that see it incorrectly. I always encourage my clients to not ask for these kind of email designs that are 6-12 images grouped up in a table. However, there will always be the ones that insist it be done and even after I show them the results in multiple mail clients they still request it be done.

Avoid it if you can. Unfortunately, there is really no guaranteed fix.

If you are sending the email to a group of recipients that are all in the same mail client you can probably solve it with one of the codes above to find the one your mail client responds to best.

Answer (score -1):

a lot of times it could be user error. when you slice in photoshop, make sure ALL SLICES ARE TOUCHING. if there is a 1px gap, then that will screw everything up!!!

also, here's a trick i learned....

Set all images to have a   border="0"  tag after the alt=""...

if there are any 
        **  ** tags, and i mean only 
        , not

so  for example....

try that, and make sure all images have border="0" and all  tags have a set width, all slices are touching, and you should have 0 gaps.

Comment: This answer needs more effort put into it.